# Catels ViewModelBase.SaveAsync method - what to do in "Child-Dialog"

Tags: catel

I have a question about the SaveAsync method - imagine the following Scenario:

- Your main "Data" (e.g. Customer) has "Sub-Data" (e.g. Order), now you want to add / edit / delete one of those "Sub-Data-Rows", but want to do the saving Action on the "parent" (Customer).

What should the "Sub-Data-Row"'s ViewModel (OrderViewModel) do in the SaveAsync?
Would you include some Parameter in ViewModel to enable saving-behavior and evaluate that in the SaveAsync call?
Or probably create a "OrderBaseViewModel" which does not save, and then inherit from that two concrete ViewModels (one that saves, one that does not)

Regards

Johannes Colmsee

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to always cancel the child views unless the user explicitly saves the parent. A save on the parent will always drill down to the lower view models.

Comment: Hmmm..."Always cancel the child views unless the user explicitly saves the parent" - how would I know, if the call to SaveChanges comes from parent or not?

Comment: One idea which came to mind is this: my ViewModels have a "UnitOfWork", which is used to save the changes to the persistence store. in "SaveChangesAsync", i could do something like this: "if (this.uow != null) { return await this.uow.SaveChangesAsync(); } else { return true; }....so - in one case ("standalone") a UnitOfWork would be supplied, in the other ("ChildView") the UnitOfWork would be "null" and the SaveChanges would only apply the changes (but not save to persistence store)